# Not able to access service in directive in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-services

I am new in angular and stuck in a conceptual problem. I am not able to access "game" service in "helloWorld" directive.

expected = Name : WarCraft

Actual = Name :

Here is my js and html file :

JS code :

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.provider("game", function () {
    var type;
    return {
        setType: function (value) {
            type = value;
        },
        $get: function () {
            return {
                title: type + "Craft"
            };
        }
    };
});

app.config(function (gameProvider) {
    gameProvider.setType("War");
});

app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope,game) {
    $scope.title = game.title;
});

app.directive('helloWorld', ["game",function (game) {
    return {
        template: 'Name : {{game.title}}'
    };
}])
```

HTML :

```
<title>Services</title>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="my-file.js"></script>
</head>
    <body ng-app="app">

        <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">{{title}} </div>
        <hello-world></hello-world>
    </body>
```

Comment: game isn't available on your scope.

If you use a directive you should use a return a object with a link-function there you can set a property of your scope to the service. 

like:  link: {.....,function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
scope.game = game;}

Comment: I have injected game in directive. it will not work like it?

Comment: yes you injected it, like you inject it to the controller, but if you look at your appCtrl, you also need to do: $scope.title= game.title;

Comment: We can not use game.title directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
  app.directive('helloWorld', ["game",function (game) {
  return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {},
  link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
    scope.title = game.title;
  },
  template: 'Name : {{title}}'
};
}])
```

Comment: template : 'Name : {{game.title}}' ?

Comment: There still is no game in the scope

Comment: And the scope should be isolate to avoid polluting the controller scope

Comment: sorry, it should be title because the scope has no game.title...
I have already edited it. 

yes, you could also isolate the scope

Answer (score 0):

Access your game service in `controller`, which will be available in your `template`. If you need it only in `template`, inject it only in `controller`... your `link` or other function need not know.

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function () {
    return {
        controller: function($scope, game) {
           $scope.game = game;
        },
        template: 'Name : {{game.title}}'
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is **solution** on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dniGGe31mOWp0xqzHAaw?p=preview), to play around.

Just put define variable which will be used by view and set to it needed value.

```
app.directive('helloWorld', ["game", function(game) {
  return {
    template: 'Name : {{game.title}}',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.game = game;
    }
   };
}])
```